# Creating Burger Menu Animation with CSS

Tags: css, animation

Hi I've just been creating this burger menu but once clicked I require the menu to collapse then create an X. I've got the animation correct as seen below :

```
    .burger-menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1002;
  .burger-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 2px;
    background: $black;
    &:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 9px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 35px;
      background: $black;

    }
    &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: -9px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 35px;
      background: $black;
    }
  }
  .burger-menu-active {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 35px;
    background: $black;
    transition: all 0ms 300ms;
    &:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 2px;
      width: 35px;
      background: $black;
      //transform: rotate(-45deg);
      //transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
      transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);

    }
    &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 2px;
      width: 35px;
      background: $black;
      animation: BurgerMenuBottomActive 4s;
    }
  }
}

  @keyframes BurgerMenuBottomActive {
0% {bottom: -9px;}
50% {transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);}
100% {transform: rotate(45deg);transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);} 

}
```

See Semi Broke fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zqdhy6sh/3/

The Problem I'm having is that the Keyframes animation is pretty much happening all at once, I've added more steps and makes no change, It rotates as it is moving closer to the line.

Has anyone got any Idea how to make it in steps. I know keyframe is meant to be steps but it doesn't work quite right

Comment: Why don't you make a </> snippet of this code and a working demo (using the create snippet button)? It's hard for people to compile animations in their heads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a this one https://jsfiddle.net/jfyzg7jj/14/

```js
$navToggle = $("#navToggle");

/**
 * Open Nav if(!hasClass['active'])
 * else close Nav
 */
function toggleNav() {
 if (!$navToggle.hasClass('active')) $navToggle.addClass('active');
 else $navToggle.removeClass('active');
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 $navToggle.click(function () {
  toggleNav();
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
#navToggle {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#navToggle span {
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 50ms ease-out;
}
#navToggle span:before, #navToggle span:after {
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
#navToggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#navToggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#navToggle span,
#navToggle span:before,
#navToggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#navToggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#navToggle.active span:before, #navToggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#navToggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #333;
}
#navToggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="navToggle" class="">
    <span></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you :)